# Potential drawing defect in Seaborn's 'heatmap' (?)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

Consider the following code:

```
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():

    dst = np.ones((100,100),dtype=np.float32)

    ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 17))
    sb.heatmap(dst, linewidths=.5, vmax=np.max(dst), vmin=np.min(dst), square=True, cmap="RdYlBu_r", cbar=False).get_figure().savefig("sb_save.png")

    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Now the saved plot looks like this,
[image]
which is clearly irregular; on the other hand, this is the output of *plt.show()*,
[image]
which although on a closer look you would still be able to recognize the uneven size of its square cells, it's overall acceptable.

The behavior might have been triggered because of the particulars of invoking *savefig* but I don't know of an alternative to try here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can reproduce this using matplotlib directly, without seaborn imported: `ax.pcolormesh(dst, linewidths=.5, cmap="RdYlBu_r", edgecolor="white")`. So this is probably more of a matplotlib question.

Comment: Thank you so much; based on what you said, I was just experimenting with the figure size and it seems that the irregular pattern is dependent on the size of produced figure relative to internals of the plot. In this particular case of a 100x100 matrix with .5 linewidths the `figsize=(16, 16)` parameter seems to produce an acceptable output --although you could see the ripples.

Comment: This looks like an [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) issue. As you have noticed, increasing the figure size seems to fix the problem. If you have a fixed figure size, you can always increase the resolution (e.g. add `dpi=450` to the your savefig command)

Comment: Thank you! I learned something useful and interesting.